# Is it possible that some action or someone altered my history?

Tags: discussion, bug

In yet another seemingly hallucinatory experience, I am being called to task by some users because I "voted" to close [a question as a duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/510714/word-for-something-that-used-to-be-popular-but-not-anymore) in a very questionable VTC.

As far as I can remember, I voted to close the question as "unclear".
The problem is that the action is *no longer in my EL&U.SE history*, so I cannot prove it one way or the other.

Is it possible that a Mod action can delete a user history? I am seeing a gold-badge claim on the close, so does that make  difference?

I have checked the "All Actions" history *three times with my glasses*, and still I do not see it. However, there is this under "closure"...

[image]

Comments can disappear from user history, but is it possible for close/delete/re-open/ votes and reasons to disappear?

Answer (score 9):

For the sake of your sanity, I can confirm that you really did use the *Unclear what you’re asking* close-vote reason. You should be able to see your own close-vote history via [this personal link](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/160305/cascabel?tab=votes&sort=closure), but that doesn’t include the type of close-vote. That, though, I can see, and your memory is fine. :)

What happens is that when there are different kinds of close vote, unless it’s subtypes of “Off Topic”, it just lists that winning close reason along with all the people who close voted no matter what specific type of close vote they themselves personally cast.

But which close reason “wins” the listing when more than one type is cast? The answer is that absent a binding vote, whichever reason was cast by the most voters is the one that gets listed, and in the case of a tie (2-2-1 or 1-1-1-1-1) the last one wins.

That’s also how it works with a ***binding vote***. Binding votes are duplicate votes cast by a gold tag-badge holder in one of the question’s existing tags, or any vote whatsoever by a diamond moderator. These kinds always “win”.

In this case, all those things happened, so it was my binding vote that made it seem to you like you voted differently than you did.

People are often surprised by this, and it has not always worked the same way as it does now. There are various bug reports and feature requests aimed at changing the current or some past behavior.

- [Could the close vote banner please be made less... well, wrong?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172654/153355)
- [Distinguish close votes by reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/153355)
- [Don't say I marked something as a duplicate when I didn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269073/153355)

Comment: Gimme over night to ponder this; however, I am still wondering about the the "change" in my user history. Where did it go? I do not see my "close vote" anywhere. Is that the bug you mean?

Comment: @Cascabel Are you saying that your close-vote for that question does *not* show up in the link I gave you? I can still see it via the moderator’s timeline, but this is not shown to users.

Comment: @Cascabel Oh that's odd, hm. I cannot myself pull up the view you’re getting there as you, but this surprises me. The moderator timeline says that your vote was “cleared” by me when I double-hammered it, but I would think it would still show up in your personal history. If you’re worried about it, I’d check to see whether there’s anything about this on MSE. Agree on the need-to-sleep bit, *pues hasta la pxxx madrugada.* :)

Comment: @Cascabel Figured it out: my link was to your meta user not your main one. Fixed it.

Comment: ...even more bizzaro...I just realized that _all_ my close votes in the history for Sept. 5 have disappeared, although the "closure" link shows 10. My VTC under  "all actions" for the day after, and the day before are there, but Sept. 5 I got a _nada_ burger.

Comment: @Cascabel - Could it be because of a time shift?  I've noticed that it becomes "yesterday" on SE at a different time than my midnight.

Comment: @aparente001 I have taken that into consideration. For me the entire day has disappeared. Everything. It is is quite incredible. Thank you for your comment. Stay tuned.